# custom event .bind('click.myclick', function(){ // }); and unbind() as well

Tags: jquery

I recently found code that looked like this

```
$('.mybuttons').unbind('click.myclick');
$('.mybuttons').bind('click.myclick', function(){
   // do something
});
```

It reacts to a click event to execute `// do something`.
And what was of great interest to me was that it does NOT interfere 
with other click events. It does not unbind them at all.

I was not aware that the event 'click.myclick' could function as a named click event.

I've looked in api.jquery.com and I see no mention of this under bind.
Can someone enlighten me or point to online documentation where this is described?
I ran some tests and if the `.` is swapped for another character it no longer works so does these mean myclick is a property of the event click?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is called a namespaced event. By namespacing the event, you can selectively unbind only handlers that were bound using the namespace for any event, or specific events.

http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names

```
$(element).on("click.mynamespace", handler);
$(element).on("change.mynamespace", handler);
$(element).on("mouseenter.mynamespace mouseleave.mynamespace", handler);
$(element).off(".mynamespace"); // unbind all the above events at once, without affecting others
```

this is commonly used in plugins to make events and cleanup easier to manage.

Comment: wow that's awesome!  Does jQuery site cover this in their documentation? I want to read up on it some more

Comment: The section at the link i provided explains it a little bit, this explains it a bit more under "Namespacing Events" http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/